# Export maven dependency list to CSV

Tags: java, maven, csv, maven-site-plugin

I would like to export a dependency list for a maven project to a CSV or TSV file.

I know that I can generate a dependency list as part of the "mvn site:site" command, but it is in a very inconvenient format for my needs.

I need a simple CSV file with at least these fields: name, version, download URL, license name, license URL

Is there any existing tool that makes that easy?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/fordfrog/xml2csv could help. However, this does not help for transitive dependencies.

Comment: `xml2csv` simply allows converting portions of the `pom.xml` file to CSV.  It does not gather the transitive dependencies, nor does it gather the download URL or license information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There is no existing tool to produce a CSV list of dependencies and licenses.  Existing tools `mvn dependency:list` and `mvn site:site` will provide the data, but not in the CSV format.

Original answer:
`mvn dependency:list` is the maven plugin and command you need. It takes lots of options, but I don't think any of them produce CSV. You'll have to transform the output to CSV yourself. It shouldn't been too hard. A quick google found [this example](https://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/) of someone who gone part way towards what you need.

Comment: That will list all the names and versions, but doesn't show download locations or licenses.  `site:site`, which I think uses `project-info-reports:dependencies`, gives all the necessary information, but spread out in multiple sections of an html file.

Comment: In that case, the answer is "No". I'm not aware of anything that does that. You'll have to brush up your XSLT skills.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that nobody else has an solution either!  One could use XSLT to extract data from the html produced by `site:site`, but I'm not going to do that.    For now I'll just create my CSV file by hand.  Someday, maybe I'll write a custom maven plugin based off the code that produces the `site:site` report. That seems more direct than using XSLT, but I'm not ready to try it yet.

Answer (score 6):

I require name and version and this is the solution for me.

Unix offers multiple tools to deal with text. On Windows, open git bash and execute following command:

```
mvn -o dependency:list | grep ":.*:.*:compile" | sed "s/\[INFO\]    \([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):jar:\([^:]*\):compile/\1;\2;\3/" | sort -u
```

This outputs the compile dependencies as follows:

```
ch.qos.logback;logback-classic;1.1.1
ch.qos.logback;logback-core;1.1.1
com.fasterxml.jackson.core;jackson-annotations;2.8.6
```

Comment: That provides some of the information, but not the full set of data that my question was looking for.  I also need the download URL, License, and License URL all on the same line.  The `site:site` command generates that data, but it is spread-out into different sections of the report and cannot be filtered simply using `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [koppor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44860410/1803692), which is a clean and simple solution to get the `groupId:artifactId:version` tuple for each dependency, you can use `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to force a redownload of maven dependencies.

The URLs of the resolved dependencies are written to the console output during that process. You could possibly redirect the output of that command (just like `dependency:list`) with `-DoutputFile`.

Note that depending on whether you analyze a single project or a full project-structure you may want to set `-DappendOutput` to true.

Retrieving the License and License-URL is significantly harder, because that is not mandatory information. The simplest way I can imagine for that to work is to actually download the dependencies' jar and pom. POMs **may** include license information, and if they don't the jar would need to be analyzed.